# Spring cloud gateway customize a filter using GlobalFilter Unable to find GatewayFilterFactory with name

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

Easily I'm following the spring cloud gateway guide to create a custom filter for my gateway.
I'm following the official guide: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/spring-cloud-gateway/global-filters.html

I don't want to use Spring Cloud Gateway  built-in GatewayFilter Factories.

This is my application.yml with route specifications:

```
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: user
          uri: https://example.org
          predicates:
            - Path=/user/**
          filters:
            - UserFilter
```

filter class

```
@Component
public class UserFilter implements GlobalFilter, Ordered {
    
    public UserFilter(){
        super();
    }


    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
       return chain.filter(exchange);
    }
}
```

And in my general configuration class I add the bean as specified:

```
@Bean
public GlobalFilter customFilter() {
    return new UserFilter();
}
```

It's normal that I still receive the error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find
> GatewayFilterFactory with name UserFilter

Do I have to use the GatewayFilterFactory for global filters too? If so, where is it specified in the guide? thank you so much.